# Given a string pattern with a variable, how to match and find variable string using python?

Tags: python, regex, matching

```py
pattern = "world! {} "
text = "hello world! this is python"
```

Given the pattern and text above, how do I produce a function that would take pattern as the first argument and text as the second argument and output the word 'this'?

eg.

`find_variable(pattern, text)` ==> returns 'this' because 'this'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this function that uses `string.format` to build a regex with a single captured group:

```
>>> pattern = "world! {} "
>>> text = "hello world! this is python"
>>> def find_variable(pattern, text):
...     return re.findall(pattern.format(r'(\S+)'), text)[0]
...
>>> print (find_variable(pattern, text))
```

```
this
```

PS: You may want to add some sanity checks inside your function to validate string format and a successful `findall`.

[Code Demo](https://ideone.com/lSipbt)

Comment: If I use the pattern = "${} off" with text = "$10 off" it isn't able to find the 10. Any ideas?

Comment: Change `return` line to this: `return re.findall(re.escape(pattern).replace(r'\{\}', r'(\S+)'), text)[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Not a one liner like anubhava's but using basic python knowledge:

```
pattern="world!"
text="hello world! this is python"

def find_variabel(pattern,text):
    new_text=text.split(' ')

    for x in range(len(new_text)):
        if new_text[x]==pattern:
            return new_text[x+1]

print (find_variabel(pattern,text))
```